# asterisk playback sound when someone answers

Tags: command-line-interface, asterisk

This is an asterisk CLI question. I want to be able to play a sound byte with the asterisk "originate" command, but only when someone answers, like:

```
channel originate *insertoutboundlinehere* application Playback *yoursoundhere*
```

The problem is that I used to be able to do this in a way that the sound would NOT play until someone picked up, WITHOUT a call file involved - just the Playback command on the originate function. Now, it seems my asterisk CLI command history is wiped, so I can't find the command. Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 0):

From this source and if I understand correctly your question:

> https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cli+originate

If you create an Extension, then you can call your own extension, then use

> originate Zap/1/123456 extension

In your extension : wait for user Answer and then call your Playback file just after the Answer function (see www.voip-info.org bottom page example).

```
extensions.conf
[greeting]
exten => 400,1,Answer
exten => n,Playback....
...
>> originate Zap/1/123456 greeting
```